# Laravel mail view don't replace variables

Tags: php, laravel, view

I'm receiving an email like this:

> Hello {{ $user }},
>   Please be informed that your password has been changed to: {{ $password }}
>   on date: {{ $create_date }}
>   and has the validity until: {{ $validade_date }}

I had managed to make it work  using this wrong method:

> <\?php echo  $user; ?>  in each variable.

Why can Laravel echo the variable but not replace the view variable?

Comment: A few questions: 1) What version of Laravel are you using? 2) Are you using a `Mailable` class to send the email, if not, what code are you using to send the email? 3) What is the file name of the view file you're using?

Comment: Did you save your email view file as `.blade.php` or just `.php`? If `<?php ... ?>` works, but `{{ }}` doesn't, that suggests it is not a `.blade` file.